# Maximal $\mathbb{Q}$-split torus in center of Weil restriction of $\text{GL}_n$ over a number ring

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory

I'm a topologist writing a paper where I have to do a bit of work with algebraic groups, and I've managed to confuse myself about something very basic.

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field.  Regard $\text{GL}_n$ as an algebraic group over $K$, and let $G = R_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\text{GL}_n)$ be the restriction of scalars of $\text{GL}_n$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.  We thus have that $G(\mathbb{R}) = \text{GL}_n(K \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R})$, a product of copies of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Consider the center $Z(G)$ of the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic group $G$.  The real points $Z(G)(\mathbb{R})$ are thus a product of copies of $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ (the center of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$) and $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ (the center of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$).

Let $A$ be a maximal $\mathbb{Q}$-split torus in $Z(G)$.

**Question**: What are the real points $A(\mathbb{R})$?  My first though was that this should be something like $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$, embedded as the diagonal in $Z(G)(\mathbb{R})$.  But what if there are only complex embeddings?

---

EDIT: Let me explain where my "first thought" came from, which might help me pinpoint my confusion.  We have that
$$Z(G)(\mathbb{Q}) = Z(\text{GL}_n(K)) = K^{\times}.$$
I was thinking that for the maximal $\mathbb{Q}$-split torus $A$, we should probably have
$$A(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}^{\times} < K^{\times} = Z(G)(\mathbb{Q}).$$
Anything bigger, and it would not split over $\mathbb{Q}$, right?  Going up to $\mathbb{R}$, and it looks like we have
$$A(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^{\times},$$
which is embedded diagonally as I said above.  But I find this confusing, so I might be missing some simple point.

Comment: I guess that $A$ has dimension $d$, the number of factors in the algebra $K\otimes_\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}$ (product of copies of $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$).

Comment: @YCor: I added some more information, which might help you figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: $\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}$Notice that the reference to $\GL_n$ is a bit of a red herring; you're really dealing with $Z(G) = Z(\Res_{K/\Q} \GL_n) = \Res_{K/\Q} Z(\GL_n) = \Res_{K/\Q} \GL_1$.  As you say, this has $\Q$-split rank 1.  The $\mathbb R$-rational points of the maximal $\Q$-split torus are thus isomorphic to $\mathbb R^\times$, and they embed diagonally, *including* in the complex embeddings.  (Maybe it helps to picture $K = \Q(i)$?)